# Zend_Navigation caching

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

I'm having trouble with the page hierarchy of Zend_Navigation getting scrambled when I cache it using Zend_Cache.

Background: I have approx 50 pages and approx 300 products stored in a database. I query the database and create an array to feed to Zend_Navigation.

The cache is

```
        $secondsBetweenRefreshes = APPLICATION_ENV == 'development' ? 30 : 300; 
        self::$cache = Zend_Cache::factory( 'Core', 'File',
                             array( 'automatic_serialization' => true,
                                    'lifetime' => $secondsBetweenRefreshes ),
                             array( 'cache_dir' => CACHE_PATH . 'nav/' )
                           );
```

This works fine

```
    $struct = $cache->load('Zend_Navigation'); 
    if (empty($struct))
    {
        $cache->save($struct = self::getSiteStructure() );
    }
    return new Zend_Navigation( $struct );
```

And this gets scrambled

```
    $struct = $cache->load('Zend_Navigation'); 
    if (empty($struct))
    {
        $cache->save($struct = new Zend_Navigation( self::getSiteStructure() );
    }
    return $struct;
```

The navigation works fine if it is not pulled from the cache. Yes, the obvious solution is not to cache the Zend_Navigation, but the constructor does a lot of work to build its internal representation: makes sense to do the caching with as much pre-computed as I can...

I'm still trying to see if there is a pattern in the scrambled results. There are no loops / cycles in the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading this question, I took a quick glance at the `Zend_Navigation` code and it does not seem that there should be any inherent issues with caching it using serialisation. However looking at the Zend_Navigation documentation I found the following:

> The toArray() method converts the container and the pages in it to an array. This can be useful for serializing and debugging.
>   - [Zend Navigation Containers: Other](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.containers.html#zend.navigation.containers.other)

You may want to create the Zend_Navigation object, use the toArray() function to create the array and cache that. Re-creating the pages from an array should be fairly inexpensive, although you may want to do some testing.

Also, if possible, file a bug report with the Zend Framework maintainers so that they can take a look at it.

`Zend_Navigation` although an interesting component, and arguably a useful one is not something I use much. For big websites having 10,000+ objects in memory is not a smart idea, and the way certain items are implemented in `Zend_Navigation` makes it slow and unwieldy. Many developers using the Zend Framework have found other ways of accomplishing the same goals.

Comment: Thanks. Spot on. Looking through the code, they use spl_object_hash() http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php to calculate hash keys for pages within a container. These get obviously screwed up when unserializing().

So the answer is to use toArray(). But then further problems occur if you are caching from your Bootstrap. The answer seems to be to create a controller action helper and load it on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning about caching pages array...

If you cache the array from `toArray()`, and want to simply use `setPages($pagesFromCache)`, you need to deactive all pages in cached array for future use.

Be careful, `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc::isActive()` checks current request. It means `isActive()` of your current MVC page **still return true**, even if you called `setActive(false)`.

The only way I found to deactivate all pages is to recursively walk trough the resulting array :

```
$pages = $navigation->toArray();

array_walk_recursive(
    $pages,
    function(&$item, $key)
    {
        if($key === 'active')
            $item = false;
    }
);

$cache->save($pages, 'pages');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post; I thought there may be issues combining Zend_Navigation and Zend_Cache, but I've been able to use the **save** method on a normal **Zend_Navigation** object and then retrieve the object back from the cache without any need to use **toArray()**.

**X-Istence:** I agree that as the size of the navigation objects grow, it may become become rather unwieldly; though I'll have to dig deeper in the code to complete my understanding as to the size tipping point.

Comment: my experience has been that its only good for small sites < 200 ish pages. I'm using it for a medium sized ecommerce site (400 products + 100 ish pages) and it feels like its creaking a bit- unless im doing it wrong of course...